# Is there a way to dynamically update the SVG-animateMotion keyPoints and keyTimes attributes

Tags: svg, svg-animate

I want to animate a number of SVG objects along an SVG path. The goal is to create an animated version of the Gartner HypeCycle for emerging technologies.  I have an old animation in powerpoint, but want to make it web friendly.

Each one of the objects (which for the HypeCycle will be a technology in the end) needs to move according to a different set of keyTimes and keyPoints  e.g.  they need to move at different speeds. I have this working in the code I posted, and all is good in the world, the animation begins when I click on a button and then loops continuously. Happy days.

However, I would like to add a slider to the page so that instead of the animation beginning when I click on the button, it is instead controlled by a slider and will move all the points along the path according to a set of keyPoints defined (possibly in a JSON file).

So I want to do two things 
(1) control the animation using a slider (but still have the keyPoints/keyTimes defined for each circle so they move at different speeds) 
(2) get the keyTimes and keyPoints from a JSON file for each one of the objects.

Thanks

```html
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" ?> 
    <!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG Tiny 1.1//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11-tiny.dtd">


    <!-- style  change colour on hover -->
    <style>
    circle.circle1 {fill: rgb(0,0,22);transition: fill 0.5s ease;}
    circle.circle1:hover {fill: rgb(0,255,255);}
    circle.circle2 {fill: rgb(0,100,0);transition: fill 0.5s ease;}
    circle.circle2:hover {fill: rgb(0,255,255);}
    circle.circle3 {fill: rgb(100,0,0);transition: fill 0.5s ease;}
    circle.circle3:hover {fill: rgb(0,255,255);}
    </style>

    <svg width="400px" height="400px" viewBox="0 0 400 400" 
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" baseProfile="tiny"
      xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
 
    <!-- draw path and circles -->
    <path id="hypecurve" d="M12.967,349.469c15.107-87.283,25.932-180.142,54.214-264.61c31.17-93.095, 54.138, 17.688,65.096,53.934c11.354,37.558,23.177,74.976,34.309,112.6c26.534,89.679,79.275-25.286,92.183-45.57c11.749-18.462,20.938-43.699,69.798-48.289c70.298-6.604,177.054-4.848,224.858-5.774" fill="none" stroke="#444" stroke-width="3"/>
    <circle class= "circle1" id="c1" cx="0" cy="0" r="5" fill="#004" />
    <circle class= "circle2" id="c2" cx="0" cy="0" r="6" fill="#66f" />
    <circle class= "circle3" id="c3" cx="0" cy="0" r="7" fill="#00f" />
   
    <!-- button to start animation -->
    <rect id="startButton" style="cursor:pointer;"x="20" y="350" rx="5" height="25" width="80"fill="#EFEFEF" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" />
    <text x="60" y="370" text-anchor="middle" style="pointer-events:none;">Click me</text>

    <animateMotion xlink:href="#c1"
    begin="startButton.click"
    dur="10s"
    calcMode="linear"
    repeatDur="indefinite">
    <mpath xlink:href="#hypecurve" />

    </animateMotion>
    <!-- these are the attributes I want to update dynamically -->
    <animateMotion xlink:href="#c2"
    begin="startButton.click"
    dur="10s"
    calcMode="linear"
    keyPoints="0.3;0.35;0.375;0.4;0.45;0.5;0.6;0.61;0.7;0.8;1"
    keyTimes="0;0.19;0.36;0.51;0.64;0.75;0.84;0.91;0.96;0.99;1"
    repeatDur="indefinite">
    <mpath xlink:href="#hypecurve" />
    </animateMotion>
    <animateMotion xlink:href="#c3"
    begin="startButton.click"
    dur="10s"
    calcMode="linear"
    keyPoints="0.0;0.1;0.2;0.3;0.4;0.5;0.6;0.7;0.8;0.9"
    keyTimes="0;0.19;0.36;0.51;0.64;0.75;0.84;0.91;0.96;0.99"
    repeatDur="indefinite">
    <mpath xlink:href="#hypecurve" />
    </animateMotion>

    </svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

In the next example I'm using a slider to move a circle on the path. I'm doing it only for the first circle.  For this I calculate the path's length using the `getTotalLength()` method and I'm calculating the new position of the circle using the `getPointAtLength()` method.

I don't understand how do you want to combine animation and sliders. Please edit your question explaining this point.

If you need to change some `animateMotion` attributes dynamically you can do it using the `setAttributeNS` method.

```js
let trackLength = hypecurve.getTotalLength();

c1.setAttributeNS(null,"transform", "translate(12.967,349.469)")

itr1.addEventListener("input",()=>{
  let val = (itr1.value * trackLength)/ 100;
  let poz = hypecurve.getPointAtLength(val)
  //console.log(poz)
  c1.setAttributeNS(null,"transform", `translate(${poz.x},${poz.y})`)
})
```

```css
svg{width:100vh; display:block;}


circle.circle1 {fill: rgb(0,0,22);}
circle.circle1:hover {fill: rgb(0,255,255);}
circle.circle2 {fill: rgb(0,100,0);}
circle.circle2:hover {fill: rgb(0,255,255);}
circle.circle3 {fill: rgb(100,0,0);}
circle.circle3:hover {fill: rgb(0,255,255);}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 550 400" >

<!-- draw path and circles -->
<path id="hypecurve" d="M12.967,349.469c15.107-87.283,25.932-180.142,54.214-264.61c31.17-93.095,54.138,17.688,65.096,53.934c11.354,37.558,23.177,74.976,34.309,112.6c26.534,89.679,79.275-25.286,92.183-45.57c11.749-18.462,20.938-43.699,69.798-48.289c70.298-6.604,177.054-4.848,224.858-5.774" fill="none" stroke="#444" stroke-width="3"/>
<circle class= "circle1" id="c1" cx="0" cy="0" r="5" fill="#004" />
<circle class= "circle2" id="c2" cx="0" cy="0" r="6" fill="#66f" />
<circle class= "circle3" id="c3" cx="0" cy="0" r="7" fill="#00f" />

</svg>

c1: <input type="range" id="itr1" min="0" max="100" value="0" step="1" />
```

#### UPDATE

The OP updated their question and I'm not very sure I understand what they want

In the following example I'm using the input type range `#itr` to change the value for the `keyTimes` * 100. The `keyTimes` values are from 0 to one, the `#itr` take values from 0 to 100.

For every point in time I'm calculating the position of the circle on the curve and save it in an array.

Please read the comments in my code. I hope this is what you were asking for.

```js
let trackLength = hypecurve.getTotalLength();

c1.setAttributeNS(null, "transform", "translate(12.967,349.469)");
// the position on the track at the key times: 11 values
let values = [];
// the position on the track at the key times: 101 values
let values1 = [0];

let keyTimes = [0, 19, 36, 51, 64, 75, 84, 91, 96, 99, 100]; //keyTimes * 100
let keyPoints = [0, 0.35, 0.375, 0.4, 0.45, 0.5, 0.6, 0.61, 0.7, 0.8, 1];

// create the values array
keyPoints.map(p => {
  values.push(trackLength * p);
});


// create the values1 array
for (let time = 0; time <100; time++) {
//for every value that the #itr can take
  for (let k = 0; k < keyTimes.length - 1; k++) {
    //the current value
    let curr = values[k];
    //the target value
    let target = values[k + 1];
    // the distance between the current value and the target value
    let dist = target - curr;
    // detect the interval of time we are in
    if (time >= keyTimes[k] && time < keyTimes[k + 1]) {
    // the increment for this time interval
    let increment = dist / (keyTimes[k + 1] - keyTimes[k]);
      // add a new value to the values1 array
      values1.push(values1[time]+increment);
      // break the loop
      break;
    }
  }
}


itr1.addEventListener("input", () => {
  let val = itr1.value;
  // get the new position on the curve
  let pos = hypecurve.getPointAtLength(values1[val]);
  c1.setAttributeNS(null, "transform", `translate(${pos.x},${pos.y})`);
});
```

```css
svg{width:90vh; display:block;border:1px solid;overflow:visible}
#itr1{width:90vh;}

circle.circle1 {fill: rgb(0,0,22);}
circle.circle1:hover {fill: rgb(0,255,255);}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 550 400" >

<!-- draw path and circles -->
<path id="hypecurve" d="M12.967,349.469c15.107-87.283,25.932-180.142,54.214-264.61c31.17-93.095,54.138,17.688,65.096,53.934c11.354,37.558,23.177,74.976,34.309,112.6c26.534,89.679,79.275-25.286,92.183-45.57c11.749-18.462,20.938-43.699,69.798-48.289c70.298-6.604,177.054-4.848,224.858-5.774" fill="none" stroke="#444" stroke-width="3"/>
<circle class= "circle1" id="c1" cx="0" cy="0" r="5" fill="#004" />


</svg>

<p>c1:<br><input type="range" id="itr1" min="0" max="100" value="0" step="1" /></p>
```

Comment: Thanks enxaneta!, I have edited my question to add more clarity.  The problem I am trying to solve is getting each of the circles to move along the path at a speed defined in the keyPoints. Each circle needs to move according to its own set of values. If you have ever seen a version of the Gartner Hype Cycle (do a google search and you can see a few image examples of them), some technologies move swiftly along the curve, while others drift along lazily, with changes in speed.The slider at the bottom will represent time from 1995-2018 and the circles will represent technologies hope this helps.

Comment: Brilliant! I think this was exactly what I was looking for.  Will work with it today and add in some additional objects to see how it works with multiple points.  Would not have worked it out by myself.